# Can Plotly timeline be used / reproduced in Jupyter Notebook Widget?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-express

The plotly plotly.express.timeline is marvelous, but creates it's own figure.  It seems like I need to embed this visual in a FigureWidget to get it to play nice with the layout in a Jupyter Notebook.  So I am trying to re-create the plot using the plotly.graph_objects.Bar() that px.timeline() is built upon.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to accomplish this.  It appears that the values for the bars are added to the 'base' vector (as a relative value) not used as absolute positions.  Plotly does not appear to understand datetime.timedelta() objects.  Printing the timeline() figure version shows the values as
an array of floating point values which it isn't clear how they are computed.  I've tried simply copying them, but this ends up with plotly thinking the x axis isn't a datetime axis.

Any clue would be most welcome.  Either how to use the Box() to draw the appropriate figure, or how to embed/animate/layout the px.timeline() figure in a notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from datetime import datetime

# the data:
df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="one", Start=datetime(2009,1,1), Finish=datetime(2009,4,28)),
    dict(Task="two", Start=datetime(2009,5,5), Finish=datetime(2009,7,15)),
    dict(Task="three", Start=datetime(2009,7,20), Finish=datetime(2009,9,30))
])

# working plotly express figure:
pxfig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")
pxfig.show() # looks great

# Broken bar figure:
plainfig = go.Figure()
plainfig.add_bar(base=df['Start'],
#                 x=pxfig.data[0].x,  # this breaks the axis as they are not of type datetime.
#                 x=df['Finish']-df['Start'], # this doesn't produce the right plot
                 x=df['Finish'], # these appear to be relative to base, not absolute
                 y=df['Task'], orientation='h')

plainfig.show()

# looking at the two shows interesting differences in the way the x data is stored
print(pxfig)
print(plainfig)
```

[image: TimelinePlot]
[image: BoxPlot]

```
Figure({
    'data': [{'alignmentgroup': 'True',
          'base': array([datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                         datetime.datetime(2009, 5, 5, 0, 0),
                         datetime.datetime(2009, 7, 20, 0, 0)], dtype=object),
          'x': array([1.01088e+10, 6.13440e+09, 6.22080e+09]),
          'xaxis': 'x',
          'y': array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype=object),
          'yaxis': 'y'}],
    'layout': {'barmode': 'overlay',
           'legend': {'tracegroupgap': 0},
           'margin': {'t': 60},
           'template': '...',
           'xaxis': {'anchor': 'y', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'type': 'date'},
           'yaxis': {'anchor': 'x', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'title': {'text': 'Task'}}}
})
Figure({
    'data': [{'base': array([datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                         datetime.datetime(2009, 5, 5, 0, 0),
                         datetime.datetime(2009, 7, 20, 0, 0)], dtype=object),
          'orientation': 'h',
          'type': 'bar',
          'x': array([datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 28, 0, 0),
                      datetime.datetime(2009, 7, 15, 0, 0),
                      datetime.datetime(2009, 9, 30, 0, 0)], dtype=object),
          'y': array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype=object)}],
    'layout': {'template': '...'}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer how to embed the timeline in a `FigureWidget`, but I think I have the answer to your original problem of getting the timeline to play nicely with the jupyter notebook layout. I'm guessing you want to be able to update the timeline interactively?

I have gotten around this problem by embedding the figure produced by `px.timeline` in an output widget. Then whenever I need the figure to be updated (from a button callback, for example) I just clear the output in the output widget, create a new timeline figure and display that new figure. It's not the most elegant way of doing things but it gets the job done.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import datetime

output = widgets.Output()

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="one", Start=datetime(2009,1,1), Finish=datetime(2009,4,28)),
    dict(Task="two", Start=datetime(2009,5,5), Finish=datetime(2009,7,15)),
    dict(Task="three", Start=datetime(2009,7,20), Finish=datetime(2009,9,30))
])

updated_df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="one", Start=datetime(2009,1,1), Finish=datetime(2009,4,28)),
    dict(Task="two", Start=datetime(2009,5,5), Finish=datetime(2009,7,15)),
    dict(Task="three", Start=datetime(2009,7,20), Finish=datetime(2009,9,30)),
    dict(Task="four", Start=datetime(2009,10,5), Finish=datetime(2009,10,10))
])

# display the original timeline figure
pxfig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")
with output:
    display(pxfig)

# create a button which when pressed will update the timeline figure
button = widgets.Button(description='update figure')
def on_click(button):
    with output:
        clear_output()
        new_pxfig = px.timeline(updated_df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")
        display(new_pxfig)
button.on_click(on_click)

display(button)
```